# create a vector increased by 0.5 in julia

Tags: vector, julia

Suppose I want to create a vector in Julia. The vector should be [0,0.5,1,1.5,2,....20].
What's the quick command to create a vector like this, from 0 to 20, increasing by 0.5?

Answer (score 7):

This will create a range, which is a kind of vector:

```
0:0.5:20
```

This does the same thing

```
range(0, 20; step=0.5)
```

If you absolutely need to make a `Vector`, you can use `collect` on either of these, but in most cases you should not, and just use `0:0.5:20` directly.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. While I prefer the colon array syntax already mentioned, this could be used for more general construction:

```
[0.5*i for i in 1:20]
```

Comment: Note that this only goes up to 10. It's an easy mistake to make with this syntax, though.

Comment: actually if you want to create (materialize) the vector this code is faster than `collect(0:0.5:20)`.

Comment: But it only materializes a vector of half the length.